# Clearing and repopulating a QFormLayout

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to set up a `QFormLayout` so that some buttons show or hide the part below them, and using `setHidden` on the widgets I want to hide is resulting in a bad layout due to the form padding still showing.

So I tried this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QMainWindow>


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QCheckBox     checkA;
    QFormLayout * m_formLayout;
    QWidget     * m_widget;

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        m_formLayout(0L),
        m_widget(0L)
    {
        populate();
        connect(&checkA, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &MainWindow::populate);
    }

    virtual ~MainWindow() { clear(); }

    bool doesOwnObject(void * it) const
    {
        return (uintptr_t)this <= (uintptr_t)it && (uintptr_t)it < (uintptr_t)(this+1);
    }

    void clear()
    {
        if(m_formLayout)
        {
            QLayoutItem *child;
            while ((child = m_formLayout->takeAt(0)) != 0)
            {
                QLayout     * layout = child->layout();
                QSpacerItem * spacer = child->spacerItem();
                QWidget     * widget = child->widget();

                if(layout && !doesOwnObject(layout)) delete layout;
                if(spacer && !doesOwnObject(spacer)) delete spacer;
                if(widget && !doesOwnObject(widget)) delete widget;
            }

            delete m_formLayout;
            m_formLayout = 0L;
        }
    }

    void populate()
    {
        if(m_widget) { clear(); return; }

        m_widget = new QWidget(this);
        setCentralWidget(m_widget);
        m_formLayout = new QFormLayout(m_widget);

        m_formLayout->addRow(tr("Show Check Box B:"), &checkA);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work as `clear()` doesn't seem to be actually depopulating the form layout. The widgets remain where they were before the `QFormLayout` was deleted. And if `m_widget` is deleted then the program will crash as it tries to delete checkA, because checkA has not been removed from the now deleted form.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using [`QWidget::hide()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#hide) on the widgets you want to stop showing and [`QWidget::show()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#show) on the ones you want to show? However, from your code, it is not clear to me if you just want to hide the widget or actually delete it.

Comment: @apalomer yes, i mentioned i tried using QWidget::setHidden(bool); the result was that the form layout was still padding the hidden widgets, and everything was aligned wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what the error is and try to help you fix it?

Comment: @apalomer the code block is now a complete example. Tested using GCC on kubuntu.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not use pointers in `checkA` and `checkB`? Do you also need to delete/hide all the children or is it just a specific set of widgets that you need to delete/hide?

Comment: Mostly that if the objects should never be deleted by Qt, only by my own code; so i didn't use pointers to ensure Qt deleting it would cause a crash. It's just a specific set of widgets, around 30 of them. If they were the children of other widgets and i was showing/hiding panels, they would need to be bi-located, which i think isn't allowed b/c i don't think Qt uses refcounts, but i haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to a solution that has the desirable (or what I understood) behavior. However, I've moved everything to pointers (since is what I am used to with Qt).

Header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QLayoutItem>
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QCheckBox *checkA, *checkB;
    QLabel *labelA, *labelB, *labelC;
    QFormLayout * m_formLayout;

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

    virtual ~MainWindow();

    void clear();
public slots:
    void populate();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

cpp file:

```
#include "mainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget * centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    m_formLayout = new QFormLayout(centralWidget);
    checkA = new QCheckBox;
    labelA = new QLabel("Show Check Box B:");
    connect(checkA, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &MainWindow::populate);
    int row = 0;
    m_formLayout->insertRow(row++, labelA, checkA);
    checkB = new QCheckBox;
    labelB = new QLabel("Check Box B:");
    m_formLayout->insertRow(row++, labelB, checkB);
    labelC = new QLabel("Bottom label");
    m_formLayout->insertRow(row++,labelC);

    populate();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
}

void MainWindow::clear()
{
    if (!checkA->isChecked())
    {
        checkB->hide();
        labelB->hide();
    }
}

void MainWindow::populate()
{
    clear();
    if(checkA->isChecked())
    {
        checkB->show();
        labelB->show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what you have posted.  In my computer, this code has the behavior that you explain in your question.

Comment: i get this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnuo69tnxon6fi6/Screenshot_20180102_175957.png?dl=0 
The two should be next to each other, as if the middle ones were never inserted, but they aren't, because the `QFormLayout` is still adding padding to those rows as if those items aren't hidden.

Comment: "Next to each other" meaning that the vertical space between check A and check B should not be there? When you uncheck check A is check B hidden?

Comment: Yes: the vertical space should not be there.  That's what i have been saying about the alignment not being right when using hiding. Well in this example program no, here B is just there to demonstrate the vertical space.  But this is more akin to what I'm really doing, rather than swapping one widget for another, for example.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't happen with my code. [Check A - False](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aq3wkf9jhl3aaeg/no_a.png?dl=0) [check A  - True](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xuo1b1mqyzn5g9n/a.png?dl=0). As you can see they appear "next to each other".  By default, your `QFormLayout` inherits the behavior from the parent, maybe in your case that is different from mine and this is why I get your desired behavior. You can have a look at [`setVerticalSpacing`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html#verticalSpacing-prop) of the `QFormlayout` to define the vertical distance between widgets as a fixe property.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
void clear()
{
    QLayoutItem *child;
    while ((child = m_formLayout->takeAt(0)) != 0)
    {
        QLayout     * layout = child->layout();
        QSpacerItem * spacer = child->spacerItem();
        QWidget     * widget = child->widget();

        if(layout && !doesOwnObject(layout)) delete layout;
        if(spacer && !doesOwnObject(spacer)) delete spacer;
        if(widget) 
        {
            if(doesOwnObject(widget)) widget->setParent(0L);
            else                      delete widget;
        }
    } 
}
```

setParent had to be called.